# Unit tests failing on property bindings for reusable Angular modal component.

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've built a reusable Modal component which works fine on ng serve (no errors in the console), however when I run ng test I get the error "Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'enableCancel' since it isn't a known property of 'modal'." Why is this not picking up on my property binding?

modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() enableClose
  @Input() modalTitle
  @Input() enableCancel
  @Input() modalWidth
  @Input() modalBody
  hideModal: boolean = false;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.hideModal = true
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<modal 
[enableClose]=false 
[enableCancel]=true
[modalBody]=modalBody
modalWidth="narrow"
modalTitle="Title of modal">
</modal>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  enableClose: boolean;
  enableCancel: boolean;
  modalTitle: string;
  modalWidth: string;
  modalBody: string = "Duis ornare nibh ac risus ullamcorper porta. Nunc ultricies ultrices magna sit amet convallis. Nulla orci tellus, sollicitudin ac tincidunt imperdiet, pellentesque a sapien."
  title = 'app';
}
```

modal.component.spec

```
import { AppComponent } from './../app.component';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';


describe('ModalComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
        ModalComponent,
        AppComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by importing my Modal component into app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ModalComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

});
```